# AWS Lambda not calling third party api in loop

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, request

i am using aws lambda and i am calling third party server using request library. this library on outside the loop but on loop its not hitting even i am not getting any error or result. and i also checked on server there is no hitting
below is my code with console

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        let transactionList = [];
        // event.body is json form object with keys and values that we send
        userBrokers.forEach(async (brokers) => {
            const userStocks = 50;
            const qty = (qtyPercentage * userStocks) / 100;
            console.log("function before api call")
            request.post({
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    "Apca-Api-Key-Id": brokers.api_key,
                    "Apca-Api-Secret-Key": brokers.secret_key
                },
                url: 'https://paper-api.alpaca.markets/v2/orders',
                json: {
                    symbol,
                    qty,
                    side: orderType,
                    type: marketType,
                    time_in_force
                }
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("api call error")
                    transactionList.push({
                        transactionSuccess: false,
                        reason: error,
                        userId: brokers.user_id,
                        documentId: brokers._id
                    })
                }
                else {
                    console.log("api response")
                    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                        transactionList.push({
                            brokerOrderId: body.id,
                            symbol: body.symbol,
                            orderType: body.order_type,
                            marketType: body.side,
                            transactionSuccess: true,
                            userId: brokers.user_id,
                            documentId: brokers._id
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        transactionList.push({
                            transactionSuccess: false,
                            reason: body.message,
                            userId: brokers.user_id,
                            documentId: brokers._id
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    console.log("function before response")
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(transactionList),
    };
} catch (error) {
    console.log("function catch block")
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(error.message),
    };
}};
```

and i get below console.

```
function before api call
function before response
```

and response from lambda
status: 200 and message: []

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to execute an `async` method in a `forEach` but you have no way of enforcing Lambda to wait for the loop to finish. You should switch your `forEach` to a `map` and await all the promises:

Bad:

```js
arr.forEach(async (val) => {})
```

Good:

```js
const arrOfResults = await Promise.all(arr.map(async (val) => {}))
```